# Yarn upgrade vscode lsp version to above 3.17

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, hadoop-yarn, language-server-protocol

i am running a c++ project that integrates with vscode and am facing issues currently implementing the type inlay hints for the language server i implement.

I kinda boiled (aka: cannot find any reason why the client is never reporting the capability) after hours of googling senslessly down to "`vscode-languageserver-protocol`" being outdated.

the issue i now face is that i have zero ideas about yarn or npm because it is not my deal of stuff to do and `yarn upgrade` is not doing anything when using either raw, with `@latest` or the corresponding version i want (in this case `3.17.3` at the very least) so i figured that this probably is a question that not only requires plenty of googling keywords, because documentation regarding **language server protocol** (**lsp**) is sparingly available but a rather simple question too for people using theese tools everyday, i could ask them here.

*****TL;DR:***** How to upgrade a single package and possible related packages to either it's latest or a minimum required (in this case `3.17`) version?

thanks for your time and [the corresponding vscode extension is hosted here](https://github.com/SQFvm/language-server/blob/master/clients/vscode/yarn.lock)